# Not able to update conda environment

Tags: python

I am getting following error while updating conda environment.
command:

```
conda update setuptools
```

Conda not able to download pywavelets-1.1.1.
getting below error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/pywavelets-1.1.1-py37he774522_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

Other packages are getting downloaded properly

Comment: Did you try again, like the error says?

Comment: Maybe the company firewall is blocking you. It's too hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: @AKX i tired multiple times but same error

Comment: @roganjosh other packages are getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved with following steps:

```
1. reinstalled Anaconda
2. create condarc file with following content in it.
proxy_servers:
  http: http://username:password@proxy:8080
  https: https://username:password@proxy:8080

ssl_verify: false
channels:
  - defaults
report_errors: false
```